# ionic 2/3 how to send a file or multipart using http post

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

in ionic 2/3 I want to post a file/image/videos using http post but cant find an example, note I don’t want to use file-transfer plug-in.

any examples or code I can use??